# How to linearly interpolate to destination that is not constant

Tags: c++, math, interpolation

If I want to linearly interpolate from point A (source) to point B (destination) on a 2d plane I could do it like this. Vector2 here is a struct consisting of x and y floats.

```
 Vector2 Interpolate(Vector2 source, Vector2 destination, float delta) {
      return source+(destination-source)*delta;
 }

 void OnEachUpdate() {
   delta += 0.05f;
   delta = max(delta, 1.0f);
   currentVector = Interpolate(source, destination, delta);
 }
```

This way I can interpolate from source to destination with a given delta. However what if I have destination vector that is not constant? Say the user can change the destination by pointing a mouse cursor on a 2d plane. An object should linearly interpolate to the destination vector.

I could do something like this but it's not a linear interpolation, but more like sigmoidal, which is not what I want.

```
 delta = 0.05f;
 currentVector += Interpolate(currentVector, destination, delta);
```

Comment: What do you want to keep constant, speed or time it takes to reach the destination?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I guess I want to keep constant speed. But with constant time it would move faster if the destination was longer away right?

Comment: Yup, it would..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said you want to keep the speed constant, I assume you want this:

```cpp
float speed = whatever;
float delta_x = target_x - current_x;
float delta_y = target_y - current_y;
float dist_sqr = delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y;
if (dist_sqr <= speed*speed)
{
    // The destination is reached.
    current_x = target_x;
    current_y = target_y;
}
else
{
    float dist = std::sqrt(dist_sqr);
    current_x += delta_x / dist * speed;
    current_y += delta_y / dist * speed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I know it's not asked in the question, but could you add to the answer the method to do this with smooth interpolation?

Comment: I have a question, what is the logic behind that if `delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y <= speed*speed` then the destination is reached?

Comment: @LennyWhite There are many ways to make it smooth, and here's one I've been using recently. First, add a `Vector2 speed` to your object. Do `position += speed` each tick, and don't modify position anywhere else. Each tick, apply some acceleration (`speed += acceleration`). The acceleration should probably be in the direction of the target, and depend on the distance to it (I'd use distance scaled by some factor; possibly raised to a small power like 1.5 if you feel fancy). To simulate drag, do `speed *= 0.97;` or something similar each tick. Adjust the constants until it starts to look nice.

Comment: @LennyWhite This code checks if we're near the target (distance less than speed), to avoid overshooting it. It uses the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem).

Comment: Got it, thanks! It looks like this is a more of a physics problem than I first anticipated.

Comment: @LennyWhite There might be a less physic-y solution, it's just what I've been using. :)